# How to replace decimal number in array with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, lodash

i want to replace decimal number in my array list with empty string `""`. How i can do that with lodash?

Here my array example:

```
[ 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 1.55, 1.6, 1.65, 1.7, 1.75, 1.8, 1.85, 1.9, 1.95, 2, 2.05, 2.1, 2.15, 2.2, 2.25, 2.3, 2.35, 2.4, 2.45, 2.5, 2.55, 2.6, 2.65, 2.7, 2.75, 2.8, 2.85, 2.9, 2.95, 3, 3.05, 3.1, 3.15, 3.2, 3.25, 3.3, 3.35, 3.4, 3.45, 3.5, 3.55, 3.6, 3.65, 3.7, 3.75, 3.8, 3.85, 3.9, 3.95, 4, 4.05, 4.1, 4.15, 4.2, 4.25, 4.3, 4.35, 4.4, 4.45, 4.5, 4.55, 4.6, 4.65, 4.7, 4.75, 4.8, 4.85, 4.9, 4.95, 5, 5.05, 5.1, 5.15, 5.2, 5.25, 5.3, 5.35, 5.4, 5.45, 5.5, 5.55, 5.6, 5.65, 5.7, 5.75, 5.8, 5.85, 5.9, 5.95, 6, 6.05, 6.1, 6.15, 6.2, 6.25, 6.3, 6.35, 6.4, 6.45, 6.5, 6.55, 6.6, 6.65, 6.7, 6.75, 6.8, 6.85, 6.9, 6.95, 7, 7.05, 7.1, 7.15, 7.2, 7.25, 7.3, 7.35]
```

result i want:

```
["0", "", "", ..., "", "", "1", "", "", ..., "", "", "2", etc... ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if there is a dot after you convert to string

```js
var data = [0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 1.55, 1.6, 1.65, 1.7, 1.75, 1.8, 1.85, 1.9, 1.95, 2, 2.05, 2.1, 2.15, 2.2, 2.25, 2.3, 2.35, 2.4, 2.45, 2.5, 2.55, 2.6, 2.65, 2.7, 2.75, 2.8, 2.85, 2.9, 2.95, 3, 3.05, 3.1, 3.15, 3.2, 3.25, 3.3, 3.35, 3.4, 3.45, 3.5, 3.55, 3.6, 3.65, 3.7, 3.75, 3.8, 3.85, 3.9, 3.95, 4, 4.05, 4.1, 4.15, 4.2, 4.25, 4.3, 4.35, 4.4, 4.45, 4.5, 4.55, 4.6, 4.65, 4.7, 4.75, 4.8, 4.85, 4.9, 4.95, 5, 5.05, 5.1, 5.15, 5.2, 5.25, 5.3, 5.35, 5.4, 5.45, 5.5, 5.55, 5.6, 5.65, 5.7, 5.75, 5.8, 5.85, 5.9, 5.95, 6, 6.05, 6.1, 6.15, 6.2, 6.25, 6.3, 6.35, 6.4, 6.45, 6.5, 6.55, 6.6, 6.65, 6.7, 6.75, 6.8, 6.85, 6.9, 6.95, 7, 7.05, 7.1, 7.15, 7.2, 7.25, 7.3, 7.35]
.map((e) => {
  let str = '' + e;
  return str.includes('.') ? '' : str
});
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Aahaaa :D ty very much @charlietfi

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add on answer from @charlietfl. This is another variation. I believe it has slightly higher performance, since there's no string creation operation on each tick.

```js
var data = [0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 1.55, 1.6, 1.65, 1.7, 1.75, 1.8, 1.85, 1.9, 1.95, 2, 2.05, 2.1, 2.15, 2.2, 2.25, 2.3, 2.35, 2.4, 2.45, 2.5, 2.55, 2.6, 2.65, 2.7, 2.75, 2.8, 2.85, 2.9, 2.95, 3, 3.05, 3.1, 3.15, 3.2, 3.25, 3.3, 3.35, 3.4, 3.45, 3.5, 3.55, 3.6, 3.65, 3.7, 3.75, 3.8, 3.85, 3.9, 3.95, 4, 4.05, 4.1, 4.15, 4.2, 4.25, 4.3, 4.35, 4.4, 4.45, 4.5, 4.55, 4.6, 4.65, 4.7, 4.75, 4.8, 4.85, 4.9, 4.95, 5, 5.05, 5.1, 5.15, 5.2, 5.25, 5.3, 5.35, 5.4, 5.45, 5.5, 5.55, 5.6, 5.65, 5.7, 5.75, 5.8, 5.85, 5.9, 5.95, 6, 6.05, 6.1, 6.15, 6.2, 6.25, 6.3, 6.35, 6.4, 6.45, 6.5, 6.55, 6.6, 6.65, 6.7, 6.75, 6.8, 6.85, 6.9, 6.95, 7, 7.05, 7.1, 7.15, 7.2, 7.25, 7.3, 7.35]
.map((e) => {
  return e % 1 === 0 ? e : '';
});
console.log(data)
```